# SustainSys duplicates Asp.net session cookie

Tags: c#, saml, sustainsys-saml2

I am trying to create a Saml sign request using Sustainsys library(v2.2) .HttpResponse already has the SessionId and while adding the Saml2 Cookie using the below code.The Already existing Session id is duplicated .This is causing issues in the Stickiness of the sessions created in the loadbalancer . Any Idea how to resolve this issue ?

```
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(commandResult.SetCookieName))
            {
                var protectedData = HttpRequestData.ConvertBinaryData(
                        MachineKey.Protect(
                            commandResult.GetSerializedRequestState(),
                            HttpRequestBaseExtensions.ProtectionPurpose));

                response.SetCookie(new HttpCookie(
                    commandResult.SetCookieName,
                    protectedData)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true
                });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Kentor.OwinCookieSaver package? That could cause the behaviour you are seeing. If you do, please remove that package as it is legacy and instead use the SystemWebCookieManager solution: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/wiki/System.Web-response-cookie-integration-issues

Comment: We are using Legacy aspx framework but not aspnetcore .

Comment: Did you install the Kentor.OwinCookieSaver package in your project?